Apache Poi. How do I create an anchor in a page such that I can use a url link to jump to that part of the document?
I'm building a document which has 10 specific reports.  There's a table with an overview of each report, who the audience is, what the data source was, etc.  I need to have a link which can be clicked to allow the user to jump to that section.
I can create a link in Apache Poi easily. But I can't find how to set an anchor on a page so I have a target to link to.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53658950/generate-inter-document-hyperlink-with-apache-poi-in-java/53670881#53670881

Alex, once again I thank you for your knowledge of Apache Poi and your quick response.
